# boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket has no member named async_accept error

Tags: boost-asio

I am using boost library to make an asynchronous TCP server.

a part of the code is:

```
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

TcpServer::TcpServer(unsigned short port) :
  acceptor(ioService, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port)),
  socket(ioService)
{
}

void TcpServer::acceptConnection() {

  acceptor.async_accept(socket, boost::bind(&TcpServer::handleAccept,this,
       boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}
```

i am getting an error "boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket has no member named async_accept"

I have used the implementation as given in
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp

please help me resolve the error

Answer (score 1):

It would be useful to show your declaration of `acceptor`.
In the example implementation that you reference it is:

```
tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
```

The error indicates that your declaration is:

```
tcp::socket acceptor;
```